# CSRF with a dockerized Flask application on AWS Fargate

Tags: docker, flask, csrf, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-ecs

I made a docker container with a pretty simple web app: https://github.com/liquidcarbon/dockerflask2fa
The whole thing behaves well locally and when you're accessing via the ELB endpoint:
http://dockerflask2faloadbalancer-f10e5f558aaa921f.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5000

But when I use my Cloudfront distribution that lives on my domain, logging in does not work, returning "CSRF tokens do not match" message on registering a new user, and or logging in as an existing user.
https://flask.albond.xyz

The Cloudfront Cache Policy was set to CachingDisabled.

I'm new to web security, and I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the caching & cookies behavior needs to be tweaked in Cloudfront: https://github.com/liquidcarbon/dockerflask2fa